# How can I get all combinations of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I am trying to get all combinations of a list. Here is an example:

```py
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> combo = something
>>> print(combo)
[1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 21, 23, 31, 32, 123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321]
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l = list(itertools.permutations(numbers))
>>> print(l)
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
```

How do I get the output `[1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 21, 23, 31, 32, 123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321]`?

Comment: Is this function what you're looking for? https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: @ncasale No. That makes it do all possible combinations, except it won't repeat, such as  ```(1, 2 3)``` and ```(2, 1, 3)``` won't be in the same list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working code:

```
import itertools

numbers = [1, 2, 3]
result = []
for n in range(1, len(numbers) + 1):
    for x in itertools.permutations(numbers, n):  # n - length of each permutation
        result.append(int(''.join(map(str, x))))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 21, 23, 31, 32, 123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321]
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the function you are looking at is:

> ```
> itertools.combinations(iterable, r)
> ```

It does the combination of the array *iterable* in *r* elements.

So:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> numbers = [1,2,3]
>>> l = list(itertools.combinations(numbers,2)) # combinations of two
>>> print(l)
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

You can have more details at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).